# If field value null Then "N/A" in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have created multiple reports in `crystal reports 2008` but can not figure out how to use a conditional statement in the report. The conditional statement is `If a field in the report is null, THEN "NA"`

Would something like the below in the Format Editor... common tab... suppress section formula work

```
If isNull({str1.strmname}) THEN
  "N/A"
else
str1.strmname
```

Thank you :).

Comment: That formula should work fine but not as a suppression. What are you trying to do?

Comment: You cant write this in supression formula

Comment: I have 5 fields in a report that get populated.  To each field I wanted to add the above code to check if the field is null then "N/A" otherwise use the value.  I am just not sure where to put the code.  Thank you :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new formula... Use that code but make sure and place {} around your field in the else portion and place it in the details section or where ever you want the output of {str1.strmname} to be seen on the report.

```
If isNull({str1.strmname}) THEN
  "N/A"
else
{str1.strmname}
```

Comment: This will fail if you have Convert database NULL values to Default option checked from the Report Options. Because then it will no longer be a null and convert to string.. So you would need both Isnull({str1.strmname}) OR   {str1.strmname} = ""

Comment: He would have to manually select default value for null as the default is exception for null. However I do agree with you and best practice would be to add the code recommended by aMazing